# Why I get just one coef_, when I am doing my linear regression with sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

This is my code and the output below. I am trying it with sklearn-lib, witch works. Is maybe x.reshape false ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sympy.stats import E

#My Data
y = np.array([1.88,3.65,5.86,8.43,11.47,15.98])
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

linreg = LinearRegression()

#Grafikgrösse einstellen
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
linreg.fit(x,y)

y_pred = linreg.predict(x)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y_pred, color="red")
plt.title("'Linearer Verlauf' durch t=0")
plt.xlabel("Anzahl Umdrehungen")
plt.ylabel("Periode(s)")
plt.legend(['t1'])
plt.show()
print("r^2 =",linreg.score(x,y))
print(linreg.coef_)
```

[image: My output]

Comment: Are you looking for `intercept_` attribute?

Comment: Your `x` has only one feature (one x-value for each y-value), so your model can only have one `coef_`

Comment: I want the a and b coefficients of y = ax +b @IbrahimBerber

Comment: No i calculatet it and b shoud be -1.77, a is correct @dm2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Equation: `y = a*x + b`

Your `a` is calculated by `linreg.coef_` term and it has one value (since only one term dependent on `x`. The `+b` term is accessed by `linreg.intercept_`, which gives `-1.7746`.